# how to implement constrained generic along side base class

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I have a base class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
    internal class BaseClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        internal void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            // Logic...
        }
    }
```

Naturally, any class that inherits off the base class can use the `OnPropertyChanged` method without issues.

My problem starts when I start playing with constrained generics. The moment I constrain a generic to any specified interface, the derived class can no longer make use of the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

```
    internal class DerivedClass<T> where T: BaseClass, IComparable
    {
        private void DoSomething()
        {
            // Logic...
            OnPropertyChanged("FooBar"); // The name 'OnPropertyChanged' does not exist in the current context
        }
    }
```

I'd like to know what kind of implementation would allow me to constrain the Generic to an interface without restricting use of the base class. If it's not possible however, any clue as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't deriving from BaseClass here, so of course you can't access the class methods. You need to call the method on an instance of the type T that you will use to instantiate DerivedClass, something like this:

```
public class DerivedClass<T> where T: BaseClass, IComparable
{ 
   T _t;

    public DerivedClass(T t)
    {
      _t = t;
    }
    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // Logic...
        _t.OnPropertyChanged("FooBar"); 
    }
  }
```

Perhaps what you are actually looking for is something like this:

```
public class DerivedClass<T> : BaseClass where T: IComparable
```

This will do what you want while still constraining the type.

Comment: Thanks. The second suggestion works well for me. I couldn't find that anywhere on msdn. Much gratitude.